# Compute limit logarithmic sobolev inequality

Tags: logarithms, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I am currently reading a paper from Del Pino/Dolbeault about optimal constants of GNS inequalities titled [Best constants for Gagliardo–Nirenberg inequalities and applications to nonlinear diffusions](http://capde.cmm.uchile.cl/files/2015/06/pino2002.pdf).

I am currently on page 4, where the author derives the logarithmic Sobolev inequality from the previous theorem on page 3. There is one step that I don't quite understand though. The author takes the limit when $p\downarrow 1$ in the expression

$\frac{1}{\theta}\log\left(\frac{\lVert w\rVert_{2p}}{\lVert w\rVert_{p+1}}\right)$ and got $\frac{2}{d}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\left(\frac{w}{\lVert w\rVert_{2}}\right)^{2}\log\left(\frac{w}{\lVert w\rVert_{2}}\right)dx$ using also the approximation $\theta\simeq \frac{d}{4}(p-1)$.

I don't know how to achieve this step. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume that $w$ is bounded and compactly supported to not get any integrability problems. Of course, $0^p\log 0$ has to be interpreted as $0$. Let
$$
f(p)=\log\left(\frac{\|w\|_{2p}}{\|w\|_{p+1}}\right)=\log\|w\|_{2p}-\log\|w\|_{p+1}.
$$
Essentially you want to find $f'(1)$, or, more precisely, the right-sided derivative at $1$. Note that
$$
\frac{d^+}{dp}\log\|w\|_p=\frac  {d^+} {dp}\left(\frac 1 p\log\int w^p\,dx\right)=-\frac 1{p^2}\log\int w^p\,dx+\frac 1 p\frac{\int w^p\log w\,dx}{\int w^p\,dx}.
$$
Thus
\begin{align*}
\frac{d^+}{dp}\bigg|_{p=1}f(p)&=-\frac 1 2\log\int w^2\,dx+\frac{\int w^2\log w\,dx}{\int w^2\,dx}+\frac  1 4\log\int w^2\,dx-\frac 1 2\frac{\int w^2\log w\,dx}{\int w^2\,dx}\\
&=\frac 1 2\int \frac{w^2}{\|w\|_2^2}\log w\,dx-\frac 1 2\log\|w\|_2\\
&=\frac 1 2\int \frac{w^2}{\|w\|_2^2}\log\frac{w}{\|w\|_2}\,dx.
\end{align*}
From here it is easy to get the desired limit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I didn't come up with the idea to view it as a function of p and using the right-sided derivative. That's really helpful. I appreciate your help.